# CRM Online 2011+ Custom Workflow Execution Time

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm-online

After December Roll Up 12 updated CRM supports the Custom Workflow.

But it is registered in Sandbox mode because of CRM online version.

So, for custom WF execution time is 2 min?? like PlugIn??

I used Custom WF instead of PlugIn due to execution time limit.

Then what is the use of Custom WF in CRM online??

Please help me from this confusion about time limit of Custom WF in CRM online version.

Any idea will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, Custom Workflow Activities inside CRM Online have the 2 minutes execution limit as Plugins.

The limit cannot be changed.

Comment: Then is there any way to run very long code in CRM online??
I thought that Custom WF will solve this problem..:)